# Radially-symmetric array doesn't work with volume shaders

Tags: modifiers, shaders

I'm modelling a vase with 10-fold symmetry. I created a single side by

1. Model the profile with a Bezier curve
2. Turn the curve into an edge loop
3. Duplicate, offset and `bridge edge loops`

This leaves me with a cut-out "slice" of the vase, with no side faces. I repeat this with the `array` modifier (around an `empty` rotated by 36 degrees) and put `weld` on top to fix potential vertex duplication. This shape is shown below, with normals visualized.

[image: Cutout of the vase, with normals visualized]

Unfortunately, this approach doesn't work with the volumetric absorption shader which I want to use to simulate green glass: the outcome looks like white glass - see below. The cube in front uses the same shader as the vase (and shows the intended effect).

[image: Vase with no side-faces]

I am trying to find a solution to this problem. I suspect that the slice is not treated as an enclosed volume, so I tried filling in the faces on its sides (the elongated, curved ones that would be created by the edge of the knife you'd use if you were making the cutout IRL) but it doesn't help with the volumetric shader and introduces some weird reflections inside the vase (below). I have also seen suggestions that the normals may be flipped, but I inspected them and they all seem correct.

[image: vase render with extra faces]

PS. there also seems to be something dodgy with the way the cube is rendered in this case, with some "cut" going through it at half-height, which doesn't seem to be a reflection of anything in the scene. That said, the shader (below) worked correctly in other scenes.

[image: the shader diagram]

Comment: It looks like you have internal faces at the junctions between the segments, care to share the blendfile?

Comment: @haarigertroll it took me a moment to figure out how to upload .blends. [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wha4JUwNKcm1gLn0gFwz9QsQO29CRQlF/view?usp=sharing) it is on google drive.

Comment: if you increase the Volume Absorption density value it seems to work, no? Your vase is rather fine

Comment: Oh wow, that was it! I just didn't recognize I made the glass so thin that the absorption doesn't show up much. Thanks. Please make an answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: *I meant thin, not fine  ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your vase is rather thin, if you increase the *Volume Absorption* density value it will work fine.